# Set azure batch cluster to run in specific hours

Tags: azure, azure-batch

Is it possible to run Azure Batch cluster only in specific hours? What variables should I use for it? Eg. from 6 am to 6pm. Will cluster be available to run in other hours if any tasks will be forced on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Batch autoscaling formulas](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling) to accomplish this via `time()`. Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling#example-1-time-based-adjustment) for an example.

Comment: Thank you. I have added this code for scaling:
$curTime = time();
$workHours = $curTime.hour >= 8 && $curTime.hour < 18;
$isWeekday = $curTime.weekday >= 1 && $curTime.weekday <= 5;
$isWorkingWeekdayHour = $workHours && $isWeekday;
$TargetDedicatedNodes = $isWorkingWeekdayHour ? 20:10;
$NodeDeallocationOption = taskcompletion;